# 'Invalid argument...' leads to fatal error: Call to a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My idea is to make a simple address-script, meaning, you put your postal code on and gets the adresses with the same postal code.

I get three error-messages:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in /var/www/tabelle/eingabe2/index.php on line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined index: `suche` in /var/www/tabelle/eingabe2/index.php on line 28
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function `quote()` on a non-object in /var/www/tabelle/eingabe2/index.php on line 31

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Adressen Datenbank">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Testside</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Testside</h1>
    <form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF?>" method= "POST">
        <textarea cols="10" rows="1" name="suche" wrap=virtual></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Suchen">
    </form>
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbaname', 'user', 'pass');
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from pizzadb2') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$suche = ($_POST['suche']);

$sql = "SELECT laden_name, vorwahl, telenr1, plz, ort, 
linkname1, forum_link FROM pizzeria_table WHERE plz = " .$dbh->quote($suche);

#FROM pizzeria_table";
#$result = mysql_query($sql);
$result = $dbh->query($sql,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!$result || $result->rowCount()==0) { 
echo "<p>Keine Datensätze gefunden</p>\n";
}


$felder = mysql_num_fields($result);
$datensaetze = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<p>Anzahl der Datensätze: <b>$datensaetze</b></p>\n";
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0'>\n"; // Tabelle beginnen
echo "<tr>"; // Zeile erzeugen
for ($i = 0;$i < $felder;$i++) {
    $feldname = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
    echo "<th>$feldname</th>";
} 
echo "</tr>\n"; // Zeile schließen

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>"; // Zeile erzeugen
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<td>$value&nbsp;</td>";
    } 
    echo "</tr>\n"; // Zeile schließen
} 
echo "</table>\n"; // Tabelle schließen
mysql_close($dp);
?>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to fetch the result after execute query and hide your real credential of your database

Comment: Over-long code sample reflects little apparent effort to narrow down the piece causing the problem.

Comment: I would delete the `mysql` tag except ... Yikes! ... there it is, in the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using PDO absolutely wrong way. Essential issues are:

1. You have to turn exceptions on
2. You ought to use prepared statement instead of quoting values manually
3. You shouldn't kill your PDO connection.
4. You shouldn't use try/catch here
5. There are NO auto-global variables in PHP no more.

so here it goes

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbaname', 'user', 'pass');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$shuchen = $dbh->query('SELECT * from pizzadb2')->fetchAll();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Adressen Datenbank">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Testside</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testside</h1>
<form>
    <select name="suche">
    <?php foreach ($suchen as $suche): ?>
        <option><?=$suche?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Suchen">
</form>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['suche'])) die;

$sql = "SELECT laden_name, vorwahl, telenr1, plz, ort, linkname1, forum_link 
        FROM pizzeria_table WHERE plz = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_GET['suche']]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (!$data) { 
    echo "<p>Keine Datensätze gefunden</p>\n";
} else {
    echo "<p>Anzahl der Datensätze: <b>$datensaetze</b></p>\n";
    echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0'>\n"; // Tabelle beginnen
    echo "<tr>"; // Zeile erzeugen
    foreach (array_keys($data[0]) as $feldname) {
        echo "<th>$feldname</th>";
    } 
    echo "</tr>"; // Zeile erzeugen
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo "<tr>"; // Zeile erzeugen
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            echo "<td>$value&nbsp;</td>";
        } 
        echo "</tr>\n"; // Zeile schließen
    } 
    echo "</table>\n"; // Tabelle schließen
}
```

last edit to fix last error

Comment: with your solution I get the hole database as array without ab table. Sorry for my question as an absolut beginner and for my bad english. For $sql-query, how could I put the form field for the postalcode(suchen) in.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: suche in /var/www/tabelle/eingabe2/index.php on line 28

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function quote() on a non-object in /var/www/tabelle/eingabe2/index.php on line 31

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting suggests that your query is failing - it won't throw an exception, but it will cause `->query()` to return `false`, which is clearly not a valid `foreach` argument!

What you should do is assign the result of the query to a variable and check it:

```
$result = $dbh->query("select * from pizzadb2");
if($result === false) throw new PDOException(var_export($dbh->errorInfo(),true));
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this line was hurting my eyes badly

Comment: @YourCommonSense The line you removed was the whole point of my answer: check if the query fails and throw if it does!

Comment: I have never seen anything like this between combined 200k reputation on SO. Hey NtDA, maybe put the 'offending' line here in a comment where it is safer?

Comment: Changed it in the lines 35 to 38, the same three error-messages again.

Comment: @NtDA -- Oww!  My eyes!

Comment: Get now the hole Database as an array.